# array saving cakephp 3 savemany

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Hi can someone know this i am beginner in Cakephp i tried to upload multiple images but it wont save.

Controller:

```
public function add() {
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    //$data = $this->request->getData();
    if(!empty($_FILES['photo']['name'])){
        $count = count($_FILES['photo']['name']);
        for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
            $filename = $_FILES['photo']['name'][$i];
            $type = $_FILES['photo']['type'][$i];
            $tmp = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $error = $_FILES['photo']['error'][$i];
            $size = $_FILES['photo']['size'][$i];
            $uploadPath = '../uploads/files/';

            $file[$i]['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
            $file[$i]['filename'] = $filename;
            $file[$i]['file_location'] = $uploadPath;
            $file[$i]['file_type'] = $type;
            $file[$i]['file_size'] = $size;
            $file[$i]['file_status'] = 'Active';
            $file[$i]['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $file[$i]['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        }
        $table = TableRegistry::get('files');
        $entities = $table->newEntities($file);
        if($table->saveMany($entities)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('File has been uploaded and inserted successfully.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to upload file, please try again.'));
        }

    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Please choose a file to upload.'));
    }
}
```

}
but when i tried to debug all good but in saving it wont work! does my code has problem, can someone help me how to fix my add function

View:

```
echo $this->Form->input('photo[]', ['type' => 'file','multiple' => 'true','label' => 'Upload Multiple Photos']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save one record once using saveMany().

```
public function add()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $table = TableRegistry::get('files');
        $uploadPath = '../uploads/files/';

        if(!empty($_FILES['photo'])){
            foreach ($_FILES['photo'] as $EachPhoto) {
                $data[] = [
                    'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'),
                    'filename' => $EachPhoto['name'],
                    'file_location' => $uploadPath,
                    'file_type' => $EachPhoto['type'],
                    'file_size' => $EachPhoto['size'],
                    'file_status' => 'Active',
                    'created' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
                ];
            }

            $entities = $table->newEntities($data);
            if($this->Files->saveMany($entitie)) {
                    $this->Flash->success(__('File has been uploaded and inserted successfully.'));
                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to upload file, please try again.'));
            }

        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Please choose a file to upload.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i reconstruct my code but same result, it wont save in database it gives error.

Comment: Post here what $_FILES and $this->request->data(); is printing.

Comment: i already edit my code at the top, $_FILES is super global variable to get files

Comment: As your problem is not clear so we have to debug it so that could you please post the data's contained by the $_FILES and $this->request->data by using pr();die;, we can decide what causing the issue only after having a look at the array/values you are getting in your controller method @MarkAnthonyNaluz

Comment: output
[
 (int) 0 => [
  'user_id' => (int) 1,
  'filename' => 'Chrysanthemum.jpg',
  'file_location' => '../uploads/files/',
  'file_type' => 'image/jpeg',
  'file_size' => (int) 879394,
  'file_status' => 'Active',
  'created' => '2017-09-18 15:32:16',
  'modified' => '2017-09-18 15:32:16'
 ],
 (int) 1 => [
  'user_id' => (int) 1,
  'filename' => 'Desert.jpg',
  'file_location' => '../uploads/files/',
  'file_type' => 'image/jpeg',
  'file_size' => (int) 845941,
  'file_status' => 'Active',
  'created' => '2017-09-18 15:32:16',
  'modified' => '2017-09-18 15:32:16'
 ]
]